# Recurrence Relation: Converting Series to Equation

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, recurrence-relations, geometric-progressions

I have a series that I have discovered within a recurrence relation and want to convert this into an equation to finish unfolding the relation. How can I convert a summation like this to a simple equation?

$$\sum_{i=1}^n 100(4^{i-1})$$ 
For all $n\geq1$.

Comment: The series is a *term* (a value, possibly an unknown value) and cannot literally be converted "into an equation".  Probably what you mean to ask is about evaluation of the (geometric) series, so that the value is "known" as it depends on $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a sum of the geometric progression.

$$\sum_{i=1}^n 100(4^{i-1})=100\cdot\frac{4^n-1}{4-1}$$

Comment: Thank you Michael, I have made the edit.

Comment: @yimmyseymour You are welcome!

Comment: @yimmyseymour You're new, obviously, so: if you find an answer helpful, you say "thanks" **by upvoting it** There are "up" and "down" arrows on the left-hand side of an answer, just click at the former one. And if you feel that the answer is really all you ever wanted to know about that question, you **accept** it (I don't know what that control looks like, since I've never asked a question, but it must be there).